# Online Schema migration in MySQL : When to start?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, alter-table, ddl, percona-server

I'm the tech lead of a Social Media SAAS, where we're currently experiencing a big increase in data amount we're storing in our mySQL-database.

We're having a single `MySQL` db, and besides many really small tables, we have two tables with approx `500k-1.5m` rows.

Currently, when performing DDL queries (adding new columns to these tables), we have to deal with quite a long execution time `(around 4-5 mins)`.

I started to search for online schema migration tips and found the following:

- [Alter table on live production databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/alter-table-on-live-production-databases?newreg=2f0779b3501e4e0b88597c1807f6699c)
- [mysql change schema on the fly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/mysql-change-schema-on-the-fly)
- [PT Online Schema Change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html)
- [OpenARK: Online Alter Table](http://openarkkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openarkkit/doc/html/oak-online-alter-table.html)
- [Facebook's Online Schema change](https://www.facebook.com/notes/mysql-at-facebook/online-schema-change-for-mysql/430801045932)

Although these tactics are worth investigating, I started to feel unconfortable at all: I don't think, that tables with such a low number of rows have to use such advanced methods. (What about really huge tables then?)

So I was wondering, if anyone of you have tips regarding the mysql.cnf itself, or other performance tips for the ddl queries?

Comment: I encourage you to read [Aaron Brown's answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11880/22673) to the "mysql change schema on the fly" that you provided. Creating a second MySQL instance as a replica of your production environment can offer the flexibility to make a number of major changes (schema changes, MySQL configuration changes, even major version upgrades) with minimal downtime.

Comment: Are the tables InnoDB?  And, are you using MySQL 5.5?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: yes, all tables are innoDB and we're using MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that Percona's pt-online-schema-change might be a better solution for you as it can do an ALTER with very little downtime. It does, however, require adding a TRIGGER to the table.

Runnig DDL on your table will lead you into rebuilding your table, mysql is a row based engine so you will suffer the **index rebuild** this can be quite expensive depending on your engine, table complexity is factor as well.